# How to exclude properties from interface while inheriting

Tags: typescript

I've two interfaces, `X` and `Y`. `X` has 2 properties, `x1` and `x2`. Now `Y` wants to inherit from `X` but don't want `x2` to be inherited.

```
interface X {
  x1 : string;
  x2 : string;
}

interface Y extends X{
  // x2 shouldn't be available here
}
```

As am new in `TypeScript`, I can't figure it out. Is there any `extends X without x1` type built-in feature available in `TypeScript` ?

NOTE: In my real case, `X` is a built-in `interface`. So, I need to do this without changing the `X` interface. Is it possible ?

Comment: No. It violates the principle of inheritance. If a car is a vehicle, and a vehicle has wheels, then a car has wheels. If you're designing a car that doesn't have wheels, then it shouldn't extend Vehicle. Inheritance is most probably not what you should be using.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you please suggest me a good method for this situation ?

Comment: No, because you haven't described the situation.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the question with the real situation.

Comment: You can try `interface Y extends Partial<X> { ... }` but then you wont be able to specify which part.

Comment: Check this: **[Sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IX%20%7B%0D%0A%09x1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20x2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IY%20extends%20IX%20%7B%0D%0A%09x3%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IY2%20extends%20Partial%3CIX%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09x3%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test1%3A%20IY%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09x1%3A%20'foo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20x3%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test2%3A%20IY2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09x1%3A%20'foo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20x3%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(test1%2C%20test2)%3B)**

Comment: @Rajesh Typescript's `Partial<X>` type makes all properties of X optional, which is misleading when you want to exclude specific properties from a type. While it compiles to the desired javascript code it "messes up" static type checking.

Comment: @sn42 can't agree more. Even i pointed that but i guess was not clear enough.

Comment: What if you wanted to exclude multiple properties? The following does not work:

    type Person = {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        location: string;
    };
    
    type QuantumPerson = Omit<Person, "age", "location">;

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### Typescript >3.5

TypeScript 3.5 introduced the Omit helper type, which creates a new type with some properties dropped from the original. The example from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#the-omit-helper-type):

```
type Person = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: string;
};

type QuantumPerson = Omit<Person, "location">;

// equivalent to
type QuantumPerson = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
};
```

*Thanks to [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063976/how-to-exclude-properties-from-interface-while-inheriting/51064664?noredirect=1#comment100698795_51064664) for the update on Typescript 3.5!*

### Typescript >2.8

This can be implemented using the `Pick` and `Exclude` types introduced in Typescript 2.1 and 2.8:

```
/**
 * From T pick a set of properties K
 */
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};

/**
 * Exclude from T those types that are assignable to U
 */
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

With these type definitions you can construct `Omit<T,K>` to omit specific properties from a generic type:

```
/**
 * From T pick all properties except the set of properties K
 */
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

To state the [Typescript 2.8 Release Notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) why this type is not included in Typescript:

> We did not include the Omit type because it is trivially written
>   as `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>`.

Although it is not included in Typescript several libraries provide their own *similar* `Omit` type, including [react-redux](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8c2749435d9defb9351eb27861d9a266f1d96c16/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L45) or [Material-UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/09896d42e6206984a54272cc2059c49a7aa9d54f/packages/material-ui/src/index.d.ts#L42).

[Here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20x2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Y%20%3D%20Omit%3CX%2C%20'x2'%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%3A%20X%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x1%3A%20'string1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20x2%3A%20'string2'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20y%3A%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x1%3A%20'string1'%0D%0A%7D) is a working example:

```
interface X {
  x1: string;
  x2: string;
}

type Y = Omit<X, 'x2'>;

let x: X = {
  x1: 'string1',
  x2: 'string2'
}

let y: Y = {
  x1: 'string1'
}
```

[image: Example of Omit]

Note that the properties to exclude will be checked, it is an error to exclude properties which are not defined in the specified type:

[image: Example of Omit using non-existent property name]

Comment: You can add this link in answer if you want [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20x2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Y%20%3D%20Omit%3CX%2C%20'x2'%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%3A%20X%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x1%3A%20'string1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20x2%3A%20'string2'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20y%3A%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x1%3A%20'string1'%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Having a debugable/ playable code/code link is always better. Also if possible, add some references as you are answering for readers and not just OP

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you for your comment, i added a link to a working example and included definitions for the used types and references.

Comment: Seems like it is available in `import { Omit } from 'react-redux';`

Comment: @theapache64 Thanks for the comment, a altered version is availbale in `@material-ui/core` too, its quite simple to implement it. Use whichever version you prefer.

Comment: @sn42 Could you please send me an email to theapache64@gmail.com. I've few things to talk about.

Comment: @theapache64 Feel free to link a valid SO question here if you want me to participate, i wont communicate in other ways sorry.

Comment: :D Haha, Totally cool. I ddnt wanted to spam the comment section of a wonderful answer with non-topic talks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173905/discussion-between-theapache64-and-sn42).

Comment: Apperently Typescript relented, they have added Omit as of 3.5.1: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#the-omit-helper-type.

Answer (score -14):

```
interface X {
  x1 : string;
  x2 : string;
}

class Y implements X{
  x1: string;
  get x2():string {
    return "sorry but x2 is not available here";
  }
}
```